# Can someone give me some clues regarding configuration of this Gradle plugin?

Tags: plugins, gradle

I'm new to Groovy, Gradle, and Drools. :-|

https://github.com/loosebits/drools-compiler-plugin

Completely undocumented. A clue would have been nice.

Having never developed a plug-in of my own, I don't know what maps to what. So all I can figure out is that it probably looks like :

```
[some name] {
 sourceFiles "/some/files"
 destinationFiles "/some/directory"
}
```

IDK if `[some name]` refers to the plug-in name or the task name. I've done some searches and not found any examples of people using it. What I **have** been able to figure out, is how to get it into `buildSrc/` since that is documented in the Gradle docs.

Answer (score 1):

`[some name]` refers to the extension name. So from [here](https://github.com/loosebits/drools-compiler-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/github/loosebits/gradle/DroolsPlugin.groovy#L21):

```
project.extensions.create("drools", DroolsPluginExtension, compileDroolsTask)
```

You get some-name is `drools`. Now what you can define in the extension is [here](https://github.com/loosebits/drools-compiler-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/github/loosebits/gradle/DroolsPluginExtension.groovy#L7). So you can do:

```
drools{
  srcDir File
  classpath FileCollection
  outputFile File
}
```

note that none of those take strings as inputs.